# import adobe xd file to c++ project

Tags: c++, adobe

so im working on a bot and made an interface for it in adobe xd. My question is: can I import it to a c++ project somehow to be an executable. Im asking this because Ive only seen it used in webpages and not in an actual exe

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're willing to write a parser for the Adobe XD file format, code to render it and code to process events to this gui, you should consider it "not possible".

Answer (score 1):

The AdobeXd project file is an actual zip file. If you rename it to a  ".zip" you can open it and see a bunch of json files, folders and images.

1. The artboards are in the `manifest` file and each will have a `PATH` value
2. Each artboard is in `artwork/PATH/graphics/graphicContent.agc`
3. The symbols/components are in the `resources/graphics/graphicContent.agc` file
4. The images are in the `resources` folder